# use google APIs with python make folders and create sheets

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-client

I am trying to learn google APIs with python. While I can create a google sheet and write data on it, I have no idea on how making folders and create a google sheet in a specified folder (using google APIs). Can you show me how to create a folder and how to create a sheet in it ?

Comment: You can create folders using Drive API. You can see the detail information about this at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create).

Comment: Thanks very much. Now I can create folders with rest API, but I got error with python code. Here is my code:
<pre>
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    body = {
        'name': 'bad',

        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    DRIVE = discovery.build("drive", "v3", http=http)
    rets = DRIVE.files().create(body=body).execute()
<code>
Could you help me? Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you update your question with your current script? When scripts are written to comments, it is difficult to see. When your question is updated using many information, it helps for more users to think of the solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I post the question again. The code is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125395/using-google-apis-with-python-to-make-folders-encountered-error).