# using google APIs with python to make folders encountered error

Tags: python, google-api

With the help of Tanaike, I can make folders with rest API. But I got error with python code.The error was "**https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">**". Here is my code which I referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import httplib2
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
]

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

def get_credentials():
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,  'googleapis.json')
    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        # flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    file_metadata = {
        'name': 'movie',
        'mimeType':'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    DRIVE = discovery.build("drive", "v3", http=http)
    file = DRIVE.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields="id").execute()
    print(file.get('id'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your script works. So how about confirming the following points again?

- Remove and recreate `googleapis.json` in `.credentials` which was created at your home directory.

  - After `googleapis.json` was removed, when you run the script again, the `googleapis.json`  file is recreated. At this time, the scopes are reflected to the access token.
- Confirm whether Drive API is enabled.

  - You can confirm it at `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/drive.googleapis.com/?project=project-id-#####`. "project ID" is ID of project that you retrieved `client_secret.json`.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks a million. When I removed googleapis.json and runned the script. It worked well and created a folder. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank for your patient help. I couldn't find the accept button. It's the first time for me to find answer on the stackoverflow, and I got the anwser. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much. I accepted the answer. But I have not gained the Vote Up privilege, so I couldn't upvote your answer. I'm sorry. Thanks again!

Comment: @shenme gui Thank you, too!